# C# Printing Offset

Tags: c#, printing

I'm trying to print some A5 pages from a C# application but I'm getting unexpected results. The output is vertically offset by about 110mm so the output starts halfway down the page and is offset horizontally by about 20mm. The output starts off the left hand side of the page (so it's hard to measure the  exact offset). The output is also clipped horizontally and vertically.

For example, a

```
dc.DrawRectangle (0, 0, 100, 100)
```

draws a box halfway down the page and half the box is missing due to being off the left hand edge. The size seems OK though.

I must be missing something really obvious but I can't quite see it myself. Does anyone know what might be causing these offsets?

Comment: Just tried doing an A5 print out from LibreOffice and that has the same issues (huge vertical offset, horzontal offset) so it may be a printer problem. At least I'm not going completely mad. It's a Xerox Phaser 6500 with duplex option.

Comment: Ooops, selecting the manual feed option rather than 'automatic' seems to fix it! Still testing though. Grrrr, I thought OSes had solved these printer problems ages ago!

Answer (score 0):

This may provide a hint:

```
// Rectangle describes page minus margins.
Rect rectPage = new Rect(marginPage.Left, marginPage.Top,
  dlg.PrintableAreaWidth - (marginPage.Left + marginPage.Right),
                        dlg.PrintableAreaHeight - (marginPage.Top + marginPage.Bottom));
// Draw rectangle to reflect user's margins.
dc.DrawRectangle(null, pn, rectPage);
```

From : [Charles Petzold's Apps = Code With Markup](ftp://ftp.charlespetzold.com/AppsCodeMarkup/Chapter%2017/PrintWithMargins/)

Comment: No, I'm fairly sure I'm doing this. There's still a sizeable vertical offset and the output is clipped.

Comment: Maybe try compiling and running the small / complete example from Petzold and see if you get the same erroneous offset.  If not then maybe problem lies somewhere else.